# Format phone number in NSString according to a mask

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, phone-number

Let's say I have a random phone number in `NSString` that looks like `@"+33142981234"`

I am also getting some masks for phone number formatting from a server like these:

```
mask = " (###) ###-###";
```

What should I do to format the number according to the mask? I would like to fill in the # with the symbols from `NSString`. Is there any convenient way to do this in Obj-с?

Is there also a way to do it on-the-fly while the text is being entered in a `UITextField`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gdavis/2845766 try this

Comment: @BuntyMadan I've indeed searched and found this gist and I have to say that here the problem is different - I get different masks for different regions, I have about 50 of 60 of them and your suggestion does not fit in unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn this into code:

```
create an empty destination string that you can add characters to
start at index 0 in both strings (formatIndex = numberIndex = 0)
for each character (formatChar) in the format string
{
    if formatChar is a '#'
    {
        find the next number character (numberChar)
        add numberChar to the destination string
    }
    else
    {
        copy formatChar into the destination string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the google libPhoneNumber library. There's a port to Objective-C here:

https://github.com/me2day/libPhoneNumber-iOS

It has all kinds of wonderful phone number parsing, formatting, validation, etc. functionality that makes phone numbers easier. I use it for all of my mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AKNumericFormatter](https://github.com/blackm00n/AKNumericFormatter) library for it. It has formatter and convenient UITextField category, it's available as a cocoapod.

Comment: Great, I'll check it out when I have a chance!